# Wrong result in executing oracle query from servlet

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, servlets, sqlplus

I'm using the following code to execute the query. I want to display the result as "B010025" by using lpad command and concatenation.(25 and B01 is given as input value). But it shows only B0125. When I'm executing this from SQL*Plus it shows the correct result. But in servlet it doesn't. I can't understand this. Can anyone help me to get the expected result.

```
public class PickOfferNo extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
         //TODO output your page here
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet PickOfferNo</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet PickOfferNo at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try
    {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet PickOfferNo</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet PickOfferNo at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
        doPost(request,response);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
    finally
    {
       out.close(); 
    }
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);
    String ofrn=null;
    //String cd=null;
    //String no=null;
    String cd="B01";
    String no="25";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    //cd=request.getParameter("sec_code");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.200:1521:pdsm", "test", "test");
             Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                 conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                 //ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select to_char(nvl(max(substr(offerno,4,4)),0)+1) into '"+no+"' from offer1 where div_sec='"+cd+"'");
                 ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select lpad(ltrim(rtrim('"+no+"')),4,'0') from dual");
                 //while(rs1.next())
                 ofrn=cd+no;

                 //obj.put("offrn", ofrn);
                 out.println(ofrn);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the `ResultSet` produced by the query. BTW: Why are you using a query for this: just do it in Java itself, that is much faster than accessing a db to do it for you.

Comment: I'm using this from database. I just checked this query. Nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you haven't selected the value return by the database.
executing

```
"select lpad(ltrim(rtrim('"+no+"')),4,'0') from dual"
```

doesn't change the value of "no" or "cd".

You should get the result set and process it to access the first column in the first row return by the result set.

Following code should do the assignment. (Not tested.)

```
ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select lpad(ltrim(rtrim('"+no+"')),4,'0') from dual");
if(rs1.next()){
no = rs1.getString(1);
}
```

Comment: How to access 1st column in the 1st row?

Comment: @user1954492 See the post. I edited it to answer your question.

Comment: @user1954492 I was wondering why you are doing this. You can use java String functions for formatting a String like this. Is this just for learning JDBC?

Comment: I need to use this in android application. That's why I'm using this

Comment: I'll post another question within 2 minutes. I expect answer like this Please stay

Comment: @user1954492 You can also do it purely in android, no need to do this using a database...

Comment: how to do this in android?

Answer (score 1):

Only:

```
String cd="B01";
String no="25";
```

and:

```
ofrn=cd+no;
```

contribute to the output result:

```
out.println(ofrn);
```

So, nothing unexpected is happening!

Comment: I understood now, but after executing the query how to get my expected output

Comment: You can iterate over the result set and get the column value by name or index, as one option.

Comment: e.g: `System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt("id") + " Name: " + rs.getString("Name") + " Registered on: " + rs.getDate("date"));`

Answer (score 0):

You have never assign values to `cd` and `no`.

```
    ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select lpad(ltrim(rtrim('"+no+"')),4,'0') from dual");
    //while(rs1.next())
    ofrn=cd+no;

    //obj.put("offrn", ofrn);
    out.println(ofrn);
```

Comment: See carefully. I've assigned